# Remove all Unicode dashes/hypens from text

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am trying to remove long dashes and normal dashes from a text. I am able to remove the single normal dashes but I have problems with the long ones. I am also able to remove them, too, but then it causes problems with the numbers in the text.

For instance the text: `asdasd2 34 56 ——————————————-`

I do regex like `[\u2014\-]` and this removes all the long and normal dashes, but also removes all the numbers. `[\-]` removes the normal dash with no problems.

Can anyone help with the correct regex? I want to remove all type of dashes in the text, and replace them with nothing.

Comment: `$var = str_replace('—','',$string);` doesn't work. It only works with `[ ]` brackets. I tried `[\—]` but it doesn't work. `[\-]` works for normal dashes. `[\u2014]` works for long dashes, but also removes all the numbers.

Comment: What about `$remove = array('—', '-'); $test='asdasd2 34 56 ——————————————-'; echo str_replace($remove, '', $test);`

Comment: `var str = "asdasd2 34 56 ——————————————-".replace(/[\u2014\-]/g, ""); str;`

Comment: `var str = "asdasd2 34 56 ——————————————-".replace(/[\u2014\-]/g, ""); str;` in my situation does not work. `[\u2014\-]` also remove all the numbers. I think something else should be added to this regex to keep the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below could help you

```
<?php

$string = "asdasd2 34 56 ——————————————-";
$string = preg_replace("/(?:(?=—|\-).)+/", "", $string);
echo $string; // asdasd2 34 56

?>
```

The two expressions below should also replace all kind of hypens

```
[\p{Pd}]+
[\x{2010}-\x{2015}|\x{002D}|\x{2212}|\x{FE58}|\x{FE63}|\x{FF0D}]+
```

but for some reason I'm getting an error or a string with this weird character (�). That's how I came up with the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

See [Remove a long dash from a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361964/3832970) to learn how to match (replace or remove) any dash symbol in JavaScript.

In PHP, with PCRE, you can use `preg_replace`:

```php
$result = preg_replace('~[-\x{058A}\x{05BE}\x{1400}\x{1806}\x{2010}-\x{2015}\x{2053}\x{207B}\x{208B}\x{2212}\x{2E17}\x{2E1A}\x{2E3A}\x{2E3B}\x{2E40}\x{2E5D}\x{301C}\x{3030}\x{30A0}\x{FE31}\x{FE32}\x{FE58}\x{FE63}\x{FF0D}\x{10EAD}]~u', '', $string);
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://3v4l.org/Q0Wjf):

```php
$string = "Dashes: －﹣֊᐀᠆‐-–︲—﹘︱―⸺⸻⁓⸗⹀⹝〜゠⸚־−⁻₋〰";
echo "'" . preg_replace('~[-\x{058A}\x{05BE}\x{1400}\x{1806}\x{2010}-\x{2015}\x{2053}\x{207B}\x{208B}\x{2212}\x{2E17}\x{2E1A}\x{2E3A}\x{2E3B}\x{2E40}\x{2E5D}\x{301C}\x{3030}\x{30A0}\x{FE31}\x{FE32}\x{FE58}\x{FE63}\x{FF0D}\x{10EAD}]~u', '', $string) . "'";
// => 'Dashes: '
```

Mind the `u` flag that makes the PCRE engine treat the input as a sequence of Unicode code points (not bytes) (and also enables `PCRE_UCP` flag).

Comment: Note that it is not enough to use `\p{Pd}` to match all types of dashes. Here is a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Mp6TC) showing that some artifacts remain after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

(*assuming we're talking `php`, since your regex works in `js`*)

try this: `[\p{Pd}]+` OR `[\—\-]+`

here `\p{Pd}` matches *any kind of hyphen or dash*. See [**HERE**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

input: `asdasd2 34 56 —————---—————————-------------`

output: `asdasd2 34 56`

Comment: `\p{Pd}` was my first guess/try but I gave up after I've got a weird string like this `asdasd2 34 56 ��������������` \u or \\u isn't supported - you can use \x{2014} instead but however, I couldn't get hyphens removed using it

Comment: try printing the string ***as it is*** and see if the characters show up fine.

Comment: Well, they don't show up as expected. As I said before :)

Comment: Encoding is already set to UTF-8. Maybe I should get a new browser or try jQuery ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the character itself instead of their HexCode.

```
'asdasd2 -34 56 ——————————————-'.replace(/[—-]/g, "")
//output "asdasd2 34 56 "
```

Comment: There's no `replace()` function in PHP

Answer (score 0):

To mark all Long dashes and normal dashes in php:

```
[\x{2014}-]+
```

The Problem is PHP does not Support \uFFFF to match Unicode code Points.