# How to remove 'em' dash from a string?

Tags: php, str-replace

I've looked at other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436523/remove-a-long-dash-from-a-string-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027472/weird-dash-character-in-php), but it's not working for me.

**Code**

```
$s1clean = 'ALIEN - FILM - MOVIE – PSP – Sony - Boxed & Complete';
echo $s1clean;
echo "<br><br>";

// Remove dash
$s1clean = str_replace('-', '', $s1clean);

// Remove em dash
$em_dash = html_entity_decode('&#x2013;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$s1clean = str_replace($em_dash, '', $s1clean);

$em_dash2 = html_entity_decode('&#8212;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
$s1clean = str_replace($em_dash2, '', $s1clean);

$s1clean = str_replace('\u2014', '', $s1clean);

echo $s1clean;
echo "<br><br>";
```

**Output**

"ALIEN FILM MOVIE – PSP – Sony Boxed & Complete"

How do I remove this character?

Comment: More explanation about types of dashes, endash is the short one, emdash is the long one - 
> Do not mistake the em dash (—) for the slightly narrower en dash (–) or the even narrower hyphen (-). Those marks serve different purposes and are further explained in other sections. [link](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This specifies an array of possible removals,

```
$s1clean = 'ALIEN - FILM - MOVIE – PSP – Sony - Boxed & Complete';

$s1clean = str_replace(["-", "–"], '', $s1clean);

echo $s1clean;
```

When ran,

**Ouput**

*ALIEN FILM MOVIE PSP Sony Boxed & Complete*

I simply copied the *weird dash* and added it with the actual dash possibility and it worked.

**Reading Material**

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Thank you, but when I copy it into my editor it converts it to a dash, so I cannot do that trick.

Comment: @user3314053 I'm not sure how to respond to that. I don't know why an editor would change it, I can only suggest what the above comment said.

Comment: ok, it looks the same in the editor, but it's a different character. So I tried again and it did work.

Comment: @user3314053 glad I could help.

Comment: @user3314053 a fixed width font for editing would do that. It looks only slightly different on SO.

Answer (score 5):

The above didn't work for me but this did:

```
$s1clean = str_replace(chr(151), '', $s1clean); // emdash
```

Note: for endash use

```
$s1clean = str_replace(chr(150), '', $s1clean); // endash
```

from Jay: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#102465

Answer (score 2):

Your dashes are a mix of long dash `–` and hypen-minus (short dash) `-` -if you view your code and the title in a different font you will see the difference.

There are 2 short dashes at the start that your code removes, and some long dashes later that it doesn't remove.

Adding this will fix it (this is a different dash even if it doesn't look like one):

```
$s1clean = str_replace('–', '', $s1clean);
```

**Edit**

Alternatively duplicate the 2013 code line but use the [hyphen-minus's code](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp) `002D` instead of 2013:

```
 $em_dash = html_entity_decode('&#x002D;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

If you edit in a fixed width font both appear the same, but are not.

Comment: `Alternatively duplicate the 2013 code line but use the other dash's code 2014 instead of 2013`. What makes you assume the given character '–' is the `&#x2014` entity ? This is a wrong assumption.

Comment: @HalimQarroum it's not an assumption, see the link I posted with the Hex and Decimal codes.

Comment: No. Interpreted as `UTF-8`, the character posted by the OP is the character 'EN DASH' (U+2013), known as the `&#x2013;`entity, or `&ndash;`. You can compare them here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/browsertest.htm.

Comment: Yes absolutely. But I was referring about the character in the initial string literal `$s1clean`. You are right that the code of the OP is confusing and misleading, and also happens to be incorrect since he is not consistently replacing the same character (`\u2014` is different from `EN DASH` (U+2013)).

Comment: Where do you see an `EM DASH` ?

Comment: No, that's an `EN DASH`. Try something like this [UTF-8 resolver](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi) by pasting one of the "long dashes", you will see that it'll resolve an `EN DASH`. [See the result here](http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%80%93&mode=char)

Comment: @HalimQarroum it was a `HYPHEN-MINUS` rather than a mix of `EN DASH and `EM DASH` - thanks for pointing out the issue (although at first I thought you were saying both dashes were the same characters).  I've updated my answer. Deleting some old comments here to avoid chat.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me

```
$title = "Hunting, Tactical & Outdoor Optics eCommerce Store ΓÇô $595,000 ΓÇö SOLD";
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&ndash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
$title = str_replace(html_entity_decode('&mdash;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), '-', $title);
```